# WebRequest SSL certificate validation

Tags: ssl, webrequest

What are the cirteria WebRequest uses to validate the host certificate if it is a SSL connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete validation mechanism is described in the [RFC 5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt), section 6.

In brief:

Certificate validation is not a one-step process. It's a complex procedure that involves validation of certificate chain from the end-entity certificate (the one being validated) to CA certificate and up to the trusted root certificate. For each certificate in the chain the following steps are taken:

- Analyzing the certificate itself (values of different certificate
  fields and extensions)
- Checking certificate integrity with CA
  certificate
- Checking certificate revocation status in Certificate
  Revocation Lists and using OCSP protocol

As CRLs and OCSP responses are signed using certificates, those certificates are validated as well, giving us extra certificate chains.

So you end up validating not a single certificate, and not a chain of certificates, but a tree of certificates.

Comment: Checking certificate integrity with CA certificate: Where does WebRequest() obtain the CA certificate from?

Comment: @usario If you are talking about .NET, CA certificates either come from the remote side (the remote side sends not just the end-entity certificate but the certificate chain that can consist of two or more certificates) or are taken from Windows certificate storage (CA and ROOT storages).